# C++ Comparing Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, comparison

I have a class `Table` which has a member function `std::vector<Attribute> attributeVec();` where `Attribute` is a seperate class.

I am working with code that would like to do something of the form

```
if (tableA.attributeVec() == tableB.attributeVec()){ ...
```

Where `tableA` and `tableB` are `Table` objects.
I'm getting a lot of weird compiler errors in Visual Studio 2012 that say things like

```
binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const DatabaseAPI::Attribute' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

So I believe the vectors cannot be compared like that. **It would make my life easier if I could get this code to compile**, but how could I do that? Can I define the operator? Do I need to rewrite some of the `Attribute` class so they can be compared?

Specifics: After writing an API, I was given a set of tests which, if reasonable, need to work. While I believe this at least makes unreasonable assumptions about my code (given my API), it wouldn't hurt to implement this in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need `operator==` implemented in your `Attribute` class:

```
class Attribute {
  bool operator== (const Attribute& other) const {
   // return true if *this == other, otherwise return false
  }
}
```

BTW: As juanchopanza noticed, it is possible that you could return just a reference to the vector from your `attributeVec()` function, instead of a copy of it:

```
std::vector<Attribute>& attributeVec();
```

That would be more efficient and the comparison (using the `operator==`) in an expression:

```
o1.attributeVec() == o2.attributeVec()
```

still work OK.

Comment: Maybe a const method returning a const reference would be more appropriate for this example?

Comment: Well, I think it depends on what is the `attributeVec()` for. It maybe useful to return non-const reference if the client code is meant to modify it.

Comment: You can have two versions, but here there is only a comparison, which doesn't need and shouldn't involve any non-const operations

Answer (score 2):

Vectors can be compared using `==`, but their contained type (`Attribute` in this case) must have a comparison `operator==`. If you give that to the `Attribute` class, the comparison should work.

On an unrelated note, that his method

```
std::vector<Attribute> attributeVec();
```

is returning a copy of a vector. You have to think whether this is the behaviour you really want.

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically self explanatory, you need `operator==` on `Attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`std::equal`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/); the second form allows you to specify your own comparison function.

Example:

```
bool compareAttributes (const Attribute &a, const Attribute &b) { /* ... */ }

// assumes attributeVec() returns a reference; if not, then remove '&'
const std::vector<Attribute>& attribsA = tableA.attributeVec();
const std::vector<Attribute>& attribsB = tableB.attributeVec();

if(attribsA.size()==attribsB.size() &&
    std::equal(attribsA.begin(), attribsA.end(),
    attribsB.begin(), compareAttributes))
{ /* ... */ }
```

Ideally, `attributeVec()` returns a *reference* to attribute vectors. If you cannot write it this way, then `attribsA` and `attribsB` should not be defined as references. (In this case, you might consider writing a comparison function for `Table` that does not require generating vectors of `Attribute`.)